# Cambiar tamaño a la pagina de la librería fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

Buenas tardes amigos quisiera cambiar el tamaño de la hoja de la librería fpdf a tamaño ticket. 
Muchas gracias

Comment: Puedes hacerlo al instanciar la clase, ejemplo `$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');`. Puedes revisar la documentación aqui: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm

Comment: Ed que necesito para el tamaño de un ticket de código de barra con la imorezora zebra

Comment: Si miras la documentación como te indiqué, veras que puedes pasar las medidas como un array. Ejemplo extraido: `$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(100,150));`. Deberias editar la pregunta y hacerla mas completa, mostrando un ejemplo minimo de lo que has intentado y indicando mas exactamente lo que necesitas (las medidas por ejemplo) y que no sea cerrada por baja calidad o puntuada negativamente por otros usuarios.

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo ya leí la documentación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si miras la documentación, verás que puedes pasar las medidas como un array al instanciar la clase FPDF.

Ejemplo extraido de la documentación:

```
 $pdf = new FPDF('P', 'mm', array(100,150));
```

Explicado sería:

```
new FPDF('orientacion', 'unidad', array(ancho, alto))
```

Documentación del constructor de FPDF: http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/__construct.htm